# What kind of file should I be using when loading a database file in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, properties-file

write now, I am working on an app that is based on an application written in java for the computer. in that program, I loaded several database files into it. those files were .properties files. I already have those files, and they were fast on a computer, but they are very slow on an android. is there a better file that I should be using that I can create by just converting the .properties files into them (I don't want to re-create the files because they took several days to create, and it was very hard to do, so I really don't want to do it again) I have heard that android generally use sqlite, but I don't know how to use that, so if that is the best option, could someone tell me how I would go about using it (by the way there are several different database files, not just one).

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the .properties file?  Loading it into some database other than sqlite?

Comment: well, I probubly used the word database wrong, but what I am trying to do is, I have a very large amount of data, and I am trying to reference one of the properties depending on the situation. specifically in my .properties file, I have it so that it looks something like this:
1=somthing
2=somthing
3=somthing

and I need to reference a specific number based on the specific sinario. there are several of these files, because in different cases, 1 would be equal to somehting totally different. I am sure that I used the term database file incorrectly, but that was what I was doing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So really what you are doing has nothing to do with a database.  You have configuration parameters that vary depending on the situation.

This [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) documentation provides an overview of different ways of storing data in Android.

I'm not sure when/why exactly your config parameters change, but generally shared preferences are a good model for saving a bunch of primitive type data that needs to be accessed through the app.

You also don't say how exactly you are processing the preferences files now, but you might also get performance improvements by caching the data, so you only have one long load pause.